# Can we leave the airport with a Canadian transit visa?

Tags: visas, transit, canada

I'm traveling from the UK to the Bahamas with my wife and 2 kids our flight has 17 hrs connection. We have a transit visa.

Can we get out of the airport to some hotel or do we have to stay inside the departure area with our two kids?

Comment: What is the nationality of you/your wife/your kids?

Answer (score 3):

With a Canadian transit visa there are no restrictions keeping you in the Airport.  You are allowed to do things such as

- Leave the airport to visit hotels or tourist attractions
- Leave the airport sterile areas to check in with other airlines
- Take domestic flights (i.e. Your itinerary is foreign country A -> Canadian city 1 -> Canadian city 2 -> foreign country B)
- Leave your arriving airport to travel to a different Canadian airport to board a different outbound flight

Comment: Do you have a source for this?

Comment: I do. Open http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/visit/visas-result.asp?q2=no&country=BD&result=1 this and pick Transit through Canada. Observe how "by car, bus, train, cruise ship or boat" takes you to the temporary resident visa page while "by air for up to 48 hours between two international flights" takes you to the transit visa page. It makes zero sense to keep people holed up airside for 48 hours.

Comment: @chx Just because something doesn't make sense it doesn't mean you can do otherwise.

Comment: Sorry for the -1, but I don't find your answer particularly useful without any reference. In fact, I have doubts that it is correct. http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/visit/transit-apply-who.asp?lnktrk=visa_transit_air says that "You need a transit visa if you are from a visa-required country and: your international flight stops at a Canadian airport on its way to another country, [or] you will be connecting between two international flights at a Canadian airport" (formatting adapted). This doesn't necessarily mean that your other options are incorrect, but it's weird that none of those are

Comment: mentioned at the official page. Now, I know that your answer is from August, and the visa policy might have changed since then; but given that you marked another question on the same topic as a duplicate of this one just today, I assume you would have checked whether your answer needs an update.

Comment: @martin.koeberl With some exceptions, Canadian airports are like US airports in that they do not have sterile transit areas. Everyone must pass immigration and customs (again, with some exceptions) and then you are landside and nothing stops you from leaving the airport. This is why Canada, like the US, requires transit visas.

Comment: @MichaelHampton That's good to know and certainly further indication that people are allowed to leave the airport (I now see that my comments didn't mention what I believe to be wrong). Still I don't find the answer particularly useful without any reference and have doubts about the third and fourth option in the answer (see my comment above). Whether the wording on the visa page is unfortunate (or the list is incomplete) or the answer is wrong, I don't know, which is why I'd really like some evidence of the answer being correct.

Comment: @martin.koeberl Good luck with that. Canada's immigration web site is literally the most confusing of any country on the planet, English speaking or not. You aren't likely to ever get an official reference. Nevertheless we know how it works from experience...