# Can you go outside the airport in a foreign country when you are 14?

Tags: air-travel, layovers, minors, toronto

I'm 14 and traveling to Israel by myself. I have a layover in Toronto for 9 hours. I'm using Air Canada and do not have the unaccompanied minor service. Am I able to leave the airport and come back with ease?

Comment: What is your nationality and where are you traveling from?

Comment: If your departure point is in Canada, I don’t see anything that would effectively stop you from doing so — except I don’t know the layout of Toronto airport so it may be that you have a hard time finding your way.

Comment: It's possible that you could attract attention from the Canadian authorities just for child protection purposes. I crossed into Canadian alone at an airport once when I was maybe 15, and they did ask where my parents were. It was no problem, but it's usually something they're looking out for and you may get more scrutiny as a result. If you answer the questions honestly and nothing nefarious is up, the likely worst case if they don't let you in is just that they make you stay in the airport, which would be irritating, but not the end of the world.

Comment: Assuming you are allowed, there is not much worth doing within walking distance but you could take the TTC and get around. Whether you **should** is another question. It allegedly takes around an hour to get downtown- it's not direct unfortunately, you can't just get on a subway train and get off at Young and Bloor or Dundas Square.

Comment: PS. For CAD $24 return UP express train will take you to Union station from which you could take a subway or walk north- faster than the cheap options.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Canada specific answer**

Assuming all of the following:

- you meet the Canadian [eTA/transit Visa](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/visit/visas.asp) requirements (if applicable)
- You posses [the documents required for a minor traveling alone](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/visit/minors.asp)
- There is an airline which is willing to transport you outside of their unaccompanied minor service
- You are not traveling as part of the airlines unaccompanied minor service
- You are not traveling as part of the [TWOV program](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/department/twov/travellers.asp) or [CTP](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/department/ctp/eligibility.asp)

Then there is nothing forcing you to remain inside the airport. ([Transit Visa holders can leave the airport during that transfer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/100402/can-we-leave-the-airport-with-a-canadian-transit-visa/100409#100409).)

There is a separate question on whether or not it is reasonable for/should a 14 year old leave the airport. I'm not going to provide an opinion for that question.

Comment: Following the "documents required" link, it includes "the name, address and telephone number of the adult who will look after the child in Canada."